# How to solve Auto Haptic Vibration on Android that occurs with music?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-vibration

I have a music application and when I test it I get no vibration but users say that their devices vibrate with the music! I searched the net and found that it is may be related to Auto Haptic feature of the device..

Is there a way to customize this only for my app and for example disable it or somehow configure it to not do it with the music and just the buttons? Is there such API in Android?

And one with ideas, please share it!

Answer (score 0):

Add vibrate permissions to your application.

Auto-haptic should then be off